# How to disable automatic focus on textField

Tags: java, focus, jtextfield

When I was creating a bunch of `JTextFields` I saw that first one is selected. I want to deselect it, because I have focus listener and it's running automatically. 
Any clues?

SSCCE:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField("hello");
tf.setForeground(Color.decode("0x8C8C8C")); // for nice comment inside the text field
textFieldKwotaWplacona.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
        {

            if(tf.getForeground() != Color.BLACK)
            {
            tf.setText("");
            tf.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }   @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {}});
//for deleting "nice comment" after click

tf.setBounds(//some bounds);
add(tf);
```

Repeat that process for another text field

EDIT2 :
actual code (I believe its sscce :P)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JTextField textFieldKwotaWplacona, textFieldOprocentowanie, textFieldDlugoscLokaty, textFieldKwotaOtrzymana;

Main()
{   setSize(500,300);
    setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Program do liczenia procentu składanego");
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    textFieldKwotaWplacona = new JTextField("Ilość pieniędzy wpłaconych");
    textFieldKwotaWplacona.setForeground(Color.decode("0x8C8C8C"));
    textFieldKwotaWplacona.addActionListener(this);
    textFieldKwotaWplacona.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
        {

            if(textFieldKwotaWplacona.getForeground() != Color.BLACK)
            {
            textFieldKwotaWplacona.setText("");
            textFieldKwotaWplacona.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }   @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {}});

    textFieldKwotaWplacona.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 20);
    add(textFieldKwotaWplacona);

    textFieldOprocentowanie = new JTextField("Oprocentowanie");
    textFieldOprocentowanie.setForeground(Color.decode("0x8C8C8C"));
    textFieldOprocentowanie.addActionListener(this);


    textFieldOprocentowanie.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) 
        {

            if(textFieldOprocentowanie.getForeground() != Color.BLACK)
            {
            textFieldOprocentowanie.setText("");
            textFieldOprocentowanie.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {}});
    textFieldOprocentowanie.setBounds(10, 40, 100, 20);
    add(textFieldOprocentowanie);



}




@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Main a=new Main();
    a.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

I want to set focus to window or sth else, in order to prevent text from disappearing.

Comment: `want to deselect it, because I have focus listener and it's running automatically. ` - I don't know what that means. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Something has to have the focus, just assign it to some other component instead. Since you *did not* post an SSCCE or MCVE, I can't give you more "clues".

Comment: That is NOT a SSCCE. How do we compile and execute that code???

Comment: nah, sorry I'll paste my actual code

Comment: This is an MCVE / SSCCE (although the `ActionListener` part is not needed and you have some unused fields), good. I assume you will have a button or some other component there that can take the focus except for text fields. Is that right?

Comment: propably radio buttons. Is there way to get focused on they, or (way better) focus on window? I've forgotten to remove that action listener and some imports :>

Comment: And somebody could explain me how properly do frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I added a radio button to take the focus instead:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    JTextField textFieldKwotaWplacona, textFieldOprocentowanie;

    Main() {

        setTitle("Program do liczenia procentu składanego");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        textFieldKwotaWplacona = new JTextField("Ilość pieniędzy wpłaconych");
        textFieldKwotaWplacona.setForeground(Color.decode("0x8C8C8C"));
        textFieldKwotaWplacona.addFocusListener(new FieldFocusListener(textFieldKwotaWplacona));
        add(textFieldKwotaWplacona);

        textFieldOprocentowanie = new JTextField("Oprocentowanie");
        textFieldOprocentowanie.setForeground(Color.decode("0x8C8C8C"));
        textFieldOprocentowanie.addFocusListener(new FieldFocusListener(textFieldOprocentowanie));
        add(textFieldOprocentowanie);

        JRadioButton btn = new JRadioButton("text");
        add(btn);

        pack();
        btn.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private class FieldFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {

        private JTextField field;

        FieldFocusListener(JTextField field) {

            this.field = field;
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

            if (field.getForeground() != Color.BLACK) {
                field.setText("");
                field.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main a = new Main();
        a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

From the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html):

> If you want to ensure that a particular component gains the focus the first time a window is activated, you can call the `requestFocusInWindow` method on the component after the component has been realized, but before the frame is displayed.

That means `btn.requestFocusInWindow()` must appear after `pack()` and before `a.setVisible(true)`.

The reason you need another component to take the focus is that when a window is focused, a component inside it must gain the focus.

#### Notes:

- If you want a better text field hint, see [@camickr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311813/1803551).
- Don't use `null` layout. Pick one that serves your GUI design (I picked `FlowLayout` just because it's fast to use, though probably not what you need).
- Instead of setting the size of the frame, `pack()` after all components had been added.
- Instead of creating the same focus listener for every text field, just create it as a class and reuse it. I show one way with passing the component to a constructor, but you can get rid of that and use `e.getComponent()` to get the text field instance.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you could use the method `requestFocusInWindow()`.

This is what was working for me here-

After creating the JFrame, call `frame.requestFocusinWindow();`. This will make sure your text field is not focused. 
Then, when you focus on the text field, the event is being fired.

Comment: @Jump3r, Please mention what "didn't work". What was the result?

Comment: @Pranav text field still have no text in it, focus did't get to window, or get to it but I did't observed that

Comment: Put this line in your main method at the end- `a.requestFocusInWindow()`
Ought to work. :)

Comment: It isn't showing cursor on text field, but still text is not displayed

Comment: Using the exact code provided, seems to be working here.

Comment: I have to use requestFocusInWindow() in constructor and a.requestFocusInWindow()?

Comment: No not in the constructor. Just the main method.

Comment: as I said text didn't appeared :<

Comment: This can't work. If the frame is made visible the first component will have focus no matter what you do after it.

Answer (score 0):

```
tf.setForeground(Color.decode("0x8C8C8C")); // for nice comment inside the text field
```

Maybe you are trying to set a prompt for the text field that disappears when the text field gains focus?

If so, check out [Text Field Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for a solution.

If not, then post a proper SSCCE, because I still can't guess what you are trying to do.